# Crystal Reports and TLS 1.2

Tags: crystal-reports, tls1.2

We have an ASP.Net web application containing a number of Crystal reports that connects to our MS SQL Server 2012 instance.  To increase security we intend to disable old ciphers (< TLS 1.2) on our database and web servers. Before I do that I need to make sure our Crystal Reports on our web server are able to connect to the DB server using a TLS 1.2 compliant connection.  In order to do that I understand I need to install the newly released (2018) MSOLEDBSQL driver.  I've now done that on my Dev environment and would expect to see a new type of connection in VS2013, Menu:Crystal Reports, 'Set Data source location...', 'Replace with:'.

But I DON'T. How am I to change the reports to use the new MSOLEDBSQL driver?

OR perhaps I don't need to install the new MSOLEDBSQL at all and can set the reports to use SqlNativeClient11 that should be TLS 1.2 compliant.

Answer (score 2):

After installing the MSOLEDBSQL driver, you have a new "choice" for new connections.  So, in the "Replace with", you need to set up a new connection using "Microsoft OLE DB ***Driver*** for SQL Server"   - what you'd been using before for OLEDB, and which **also** still shows up in the list, is the "Microsoft OLE DB *Provider* for SQL Server".

[image: new entry in the Provider list]

It's also possible to change a report's connection info programmatically at runtime.  See [this SAP article](https://blogs.sap.com/2011/09/02/when-to-use-the-replace-connection-method-using-the-crystal-reports-or-inproc-ras-sdk-for-net/).